# lxml can't find element using css selector

Tags: python, python-3.x, css-selectors, lxml

I'm trying to find element in html page using css selector, but lxml can't find that element.

Example page [here](https://reality.bazos.cz/inzerat/102358166/Prodej-byty2kk-57-m2-Behounkova-253467-Stodulky-15800-Praha-Hlavni-mes.php)

CSS Selector that I'm using:  `td.listadvlevo > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > b`

```
html = etree.HTML(response.content)
sel = CSSSelector("td.listadvlevo > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > b", translator='html')
print(len(sel(html)))
```

Output of above code will be 0, lxml will not find anything. On the example page it should find `<b> 4 300 000 Kč</b>`

These selectors works fine:

- `div.popis`
- `div.drobky > a:nth-child(4)`
- `div.drobky > a:nth-child(3)`

These have same problem:

- `table.listainzerat > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > h1`
- `td.listadvlevo > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > b > a`
- `td.listadvlevo > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2) > a`

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @JackFleeting On the example page it should find `<b> 4 300 000 Kč</b>`

Comment: Kindly paste the HTML as well so we can see DOM

Comment: @Rusty page is too big to paste it into the question, use link that I provided in question

Comment: Ok will look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a dot:

```
td.listadvlevo > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > b
```

Comment: Sorry, this is mistake while writing question, corrected and added more css selector examples

Comment: Try using `td.listadvlevo br + b`